# How do I set the value of a do while inner loop, nested in a for loop?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a report that downloads from a client's SharePoint.  The report varies in length depending on the site and time range I am running it for.  Most items come across where their information is nicely laid out in columns on one row per each item, but in the case where there is a split decision it puts the decision into multiple lines and does not keep the other necessary information in those lines.  I'm trying to take the split dispositions and find loop through the following rows to copy the quantities and paste them in the columns based on their disposition.

I have the Outer loop set up and it works.  When I set up the inner loop it doesn't take the value of the outer loop and add 1 row to it.

```
Sub Split_Dispositions_One_Line()
    Dim LastRow As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    i = x + i
    LastRow = Worksheets("Data").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    With Worksheets("Data")
        For x = 1 To LastRow
            If InStr(Range("Y" & x).Value, "Split Disposition") Then
                Do While Application.WorksheetFunction.IsText(Range("AI" & i).Value)
                    If InStr(Range("AI" & i).Value, "Release to Good Inventory") Then
                        Range("AH" & i).Copy Range("AK" & x)
                    ElseIf InStr(Range("AI" & i).Value, "Donate") Then
                        Range("AH" & i).Copy Range("AL" & x)
                    ElseIf InStr(Range("AI" & i).Value, "Destroy, Landfill") Then
                        Range("AH" & i).Copy Range("AM" & x)
                    ElseIf InStr(Range("AI" & i).Value, "Destroy, Animal Feed") Then
                        Range("AH" & i).Copy Range("AN" & x)
                    ElseIf InStr(Range("AI" & i).Value, "Return To Plant") Then
                        Range("AH" & i).Copy Range("AO" & x)
                    End If
                Loop
            End If
        Next x
    End With
End Sub
```

My goal is to loop through the rows and when I come across "Split Disposition" in column Y it will then go to the inner loop, drop 1 row down from where it found "Split Disposition" in Y and loop through those rows and if AI contains text it will copy the value in AH and paste it to the column that corresponds to AH in the original row where it found "Split Disposition" in column Y.  The number of these lines varies, but they are always one after the other.

Said differently if the loop finds "Split Disposition" in cell Y5, then the inner loop will start at AI6, if it has text copy AH6 and Paste into Column AK5, then if AI7 contains text it will copy AH7 and might paste it in AL5 (if that is the column that matches AH7).

Comment: Note that row counting variables (`i` and `LastRow`) need to be of type `Long` because Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle. • And `x` is not declared at all. I recommend always to activate `Option Explicit`: In the VBA editor go to *Tools* › *Options* › *[Require Variable Declaration](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)*.

Comment: Another thing is that your `With Worksheets("Data")` is completely useless because non of your `Range` statements starts with a dot `.` if you want your ranges to use the `With` statement you should start them with a dot like `.Range("Y" & x)`. Fix this for **all** your ranges inside the `With` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Changed the inner loop to a for loop with an exit option and that seems to work.

```
Sub Split_Dispositions_One_Line()
        Dim LastRow As Integer
        Dim i As Integer
        LastRow = Worksheets("Data").UsedRange.Rows.Count
        With Worksheets("Data")
            For x = 1 To LastRow
                If InStr(Range("Y" & x).Value, "Split Disposition") Then
                    For i = x + 1 To LastRow
                        If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsText(Range("AI" & i).Value) Then
                            If InStr(Range("AI" & i).Value, "Release to Good Inventory") Then
                                Range("AH" & i).Copy Range("AK" & x)
                            ElseIf InStr(Range("AI" & i).Value, "Donate") Then
                                Range("AH" & i).Copy Range("AL" & x)
                            ElseIf InStr(Range("AI" & i).Value, "Destroy, Landfill") Then
                                Range("AH" & i).Copy Range("AM" & x)
                            ElseIf InStr(Range("AI" & i).Value, "Destroy, Animal Feed") Then
                                Range("AH" & i).Copy Range("AN" & x)
                            ElseIf InStr(Range("AI" & i).Value, "Return To Plant") Then
                                Range("AH" & i).Copy Range("AO" & x)
                            End If
                        ElseIf IsEmpty(Range("AI" & i).Value) Then
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next i
                End If
            Next x
        End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Still note that row counting variables (`i` and `LastRow`) need to be of type `Long` because Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle. • And `x` is not declared at all and should be `Dim x As Long` too.